# Autowiring a spring managed bean in the resteasy providers

Tags: spring, web-services, resteasy, jboss6.x

I have a developing a webservice where in i need to validate a particular httpheader sent in the request against the database.

I want to use RestEasy provider for doing the same as the same functionality needs to be applied to all the service.

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class TestValidationInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor      {

@Autowired
DetailsDelegate detailsDelegate;

@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
    //code to get data using detailsDelegate.
    return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
    public interface DetailsDelegate {

String BEAN_ID = "DetailsDelegate";

/**
 * @param appName
 * @return
 * @throws BaseException
 */
ServiceInfo getServiceDetails(String appName) throws BaseException;
 }
```

---

```
@Service("detailsDelegate")
public class DetailsDelegateImpl implements DetailsDelegate {


@Override
public ServiceInfo getServiceDetails(String appName) throws BaseException {
    return null;
   }
}
```

The detailsDelegate instance is not getting autowired and is null.

Can someone explain why I am facing this issue.

Comment: Would you share your config and the DetailsDelegate implementation or class.

Comment: Updated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to let spring chose it's bean names so change

```
@Service("detailsDelegate")
```

to

```
@Service
```

The autowire the interface :

```
@Auowired
DetailsDelegate
```

Finally make sure the package in which DetailsDelegate is defined is scanned in your config:

```
@ComponentScan("com.mypackage")
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html for examples

Comment: There is no issue with the naming convention. The same is working in other classes. I believe the they have different context one of spring and the other of jax rs.