# JavaConfig Spring make beans available to all application

Tags: java, spring

I have a jar with a main method. I created a java config with the @Configuration annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.commons" })
public class ProxyConfig {

}
```

In this com.test.commons I have put a service

```
package com.test.commons;

@Service
public class RestService {

    //do rest calls
    public String restGetCall(URL url){
        ...
    }
}
```

I am NOT asking for this

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(ProxyConfig.class);
        context.getBean("myBean");
```

The main

```
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.test.commons", "com.test.soapproxy" })
    public class MainAppProxy 

    {
        private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainAppProxy.class);
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            SpringApplication.run(MainAppProxy.class, args);
            // Choose environment from the arguments
            String env = args[0];
            // publish an endpoint here
            Configuration config = null;
            config = configs.properties
                (new File("config_"+env+".properties"));
        Endpoint.publish(endpointAddress, new SomeProxyImpl(config));
```

The class in which I am trying to inject the bean (is the @Component needed here really?)

```
@Component
public class SomeProxyImpl implements SomeServiceSoap {
@Autowired  RestService restService;
```

I would like to be able to inject this RestService bean through @Autowired in all my application, not only in SomeProxyImpl(which is not working anyway). How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672758/autowiring-a-spring-managed-bean-in-the-resteasy-providers/41674399#41674399

Comment: did you use scanBasePackages :@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { ..}

Comment: Autowire your `RestService` in your Controllers. That will fulfill your need.

Comment: @melihcoskun I have just done that. Autowired didn't manage to inject my bean.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar I do not have a controller, I want to inject this service to no matter what class

Comment: @grailsDude, `@Autowired` works well irrespective of whether the class is a `@Controller` or just an ordinary class.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar that's great to know but in my case it does not

Comment: First you should check scanBasePackages contains the package "com.test.commons". Second check  scanBasePackages contains the class which calls RestService by using autowired annotation. Also you can not call a spring bean from a java class which is not generated with Spring app.

Comment: You can inject beans only in another bean.  Check where you are trying to inject the bean, ie: Class should be inside package com.test.commons and should be annotated as Component, Service, Controller or RestController

Comment: @AnilAgrawal The class in which I am trying to inject the service bean has now @ Component and I have included its package in the basePackages declaration but it is not working either. I also tried with  @ SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages in the main class and with the ProxyConfig java config I posted above. Nothing works

Comment: Please show your main class. The one annotated with @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: @awgtek You are right, I have updated the post with the main class and the class in which I am trying to inject the bean

Comment: Is that the full main method? please put the full main method. It should include `SpringApplication.run(MainAppProxy.class, args);`

Comment: @awgtek Thank you for your comment, I have added it but I still have a null pointer in SomeProxyImpl when I try to use the bean restService. I also added it to the post.

Comment: You need to `@Autowire` SomeProxyImpl not use `new` on it. You can autowired right in that main class. And put the `Endpoint.publish` method in another method (not in main), put in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: @awgtek You are so right, it is the new that breaks the autowiring. But I do not know how to do it with the config argument that I pass through the constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133999/discussion-between-awgtek-and-grailsdude).

Answer (score 0):

Spring don't autowire field created by a new, unless you ask for it, like this : ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(object);

If your SomeProxyImpl class is in the "com.test.soapproxy" package, and your class is annotated with @Component, then Spring must have created an instance with the bean autowired.
You should then get this bean from your context and use it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: ApplicationContextHolder is not a class included in the spring jars?

Comment: Hmmm sorry, it's a class from our internal framework... but it's simply a class that implements "ApplicationContextAware" and can easily provide us the Spring ApplicationContext.